# How to get started with dj-stripe 1.0?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

What do I need to do to make payments available with Stripe and Django using dj-stripe 1.0? I found the documentation quite unforgiving for a newcomer to dj-stripe. I think I have gleaned that most configuration of e.g. subscription plans are done at stripe.com and updated via webhooks to my application. However, what do I need to implement myself and how?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question needs to be more specific, but I also struggled with Stripe's documentation on subscriptions and webhooks. Here is a bit of stuff I gleaned from multiple exchanges with their support:

Once you've set up the customer object, attached a payment source, and subscribed your customer to a plan, you won't need to take any further steps. Stripe will take care of creating the charges on the recurring basis that you've set.

Despite stripe's recommendation of implementing webhooks as a best practice for subscriptions with Stripe, it is not required to continue billing. Billing is attempted automatically without the need to handle web hooks.

Hope that helps.